# Clion C Debug error - pretty printer

Tags: ide, debugger

If I try to debug my C project, the debugger won't start and displays an error:

```
Error during pretty printers setup: Undefined command: "pretty-printer"
```

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

[image: Settings dialog]